# Why we cant have FPTAS for Strong NP complete problems

Tags: np

I understood that we can apply FPTAS to the weak NP problems like 0-1 knapsack.

But why we cant apply the same principal to the strong NP problems like bin packing.I also checked wiki page about the same but understood very less.

Comment: This question belongs on http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about theoretical computer science, which is more appropriate at cs.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @tripleee- Why does this belong on programmers? This is a CS theory question.

Answer (score 2):

If a stongly NP complete problem had an FPTAS, you could "trick" the approximation algorithm into giving an optimal solution.  Details are here: http://www.idi.ntnu.no/~mlh/algkon/complexity.pdf

The existence of this FPTAS would give a polynomial time algorithm for NP-complete problem.